# "No rule to make target" error when linking matlab's libraries

Tags: matlab, cmake, shared-libraries

My cmake script is as follows:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Matlab REQUIRED)

GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(Matlab_BIN_DIRS ${Matlab_LIBRARIES} PATH)
SET(Matlab_LIBS "${Matlab_BIN_DIRS}/libmat.so ${Matlab_BIN_DIRS}/libmx.so")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Matlab_INCLUDE_DIRS})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myAPP ${Matlab_LIBRARIES} ${Matlab_LIBS})
```

following error information was printed when I built my projects.

```
:-1: error: No rule to make target '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmat.so /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so', needed by 'cimgio'.  Stop.
```

But it worked after modifying the last line as
`TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myAPP ${Matlab_LIBRARIES} libmat.so libmx.so)`
why full paths does not work here?

Comment: A string, enclosed into **double quotes**, is no longer interprets space as a separator, so you have **single value** with space-separated parts. You may notice that from the error message: `make`  searches for the *single file*, which name (within quotes) contains a space. Drop that double quotes in your `CMakeLists.txt`, and everything will work. Or use `;` for separate values within quoted string.

Comment: @Tsyvarev it worked, Thanks, I got it :)